# Add columns of matrix to columns of other matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a simple question, but couldn't figure out a good solution. So hope, somebody can help :)

I want to add each column of a matrix B to a column of a matrix A, where an index vector specifies, to which column of A this column should be added to. So it is possible that more than one column of B is added to the same column of A. I want to accumulate these changes and not replace these.

This is a working solution with a for loop:

```
A <- matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
B <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0), ncol = 3)
cols <- c(1, 2, 2)

for (i in seq_len(ncol(B))) {
  A[, cols[i]] <- A[, cols[i]] + B[, i]
}
print(A)
```

I thought I could write this without a for loop using

```
A <- matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
B <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0), ncol = 3)
cols <- c(1, 2, 2)

A[, cols] <- A[, cols] + B
print(A)
```

But this doesn't return the same matrix, because it adds the second column of B to the second column of A but then in the next step replaces this with the third column of B instead of adding both of the replacements together.

I'm looking for a fast and general solution, which works also for different index vectors and matrices.

Comment: what is your desired outcome?

Comment: The value of A after the for loop is the desired outcome. But I am looking for a faster and cleaner solution

Comment: Try to make your question more clear, maybe you can get more help....

Comment: have you run into a performance issue with your solution?

Comment: It would be nice to have a fast solution because I call this operation often and for loops in R are supposed to be slow...

Comment: Loops for matrices are pretty fast if implemented properly. It's an outdated rumor that loops in R are slow in general. Vectorized solutions are almost always better, but I can't immediately think of such a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your help :) I will then just use my first solution until  somebody comes up with something faster.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't eliminate the loop, but it does make it shorter:

```
A <- matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
B <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0), ncol = 3)
cols <- c(1, 2, 2)

for(i in unique(cols)){
  A[, i] <- A[, i] + apply(as.matrix(B[, cols == i]), 1, sum)
}
print(A)
```

Comment: But it is slower. Using microbenchmark my for loop would need about 8 microseconds and your solution about 85 microseconds (median values)

Comment: It'll depend on how the relative dimension of `unique(cols)` and `B` in your actual problem. Based on how you constructed your example, I assumed the latter would be much larger than the former. This may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ans = A[,cols] + B
ans = sapply(split(1:NCOL(ans), cols), function(i) rowSums(ans[, i, drop = FALSE]))
inds = cbind(rep(1:NROW(A), length(unique(cols))), rep(unique(cols), each = NROW(A)))
replace(A, inds, ans[inds])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    2    0    0
#[4,]    0    2    0    0
```